# How to save GetLocalTime time in another structure

Tags: c++, time

I am using `GetLocalTime(&time)` function to get time in `visual C++`. Now I need to save the time whenever a input goes high, in a another structure so that I can perform further calculations on the stored time.

```
SYSTEMTIME time;
if(input==high)
{
    count++;    //Incrementing a counter to count the number of times input is high

    //Depending upon this count, I need to save value of time in a new variable
    //using GetLocalTime to get current time 

    GetLocalTime(&time);
}
```

How to store the current time depending upon the count values. Like when count is 1, that means input is high for the first time so store it in `a1`. If count is 2, store time in `a2`. If count is 5, store time in `a5`. I cannot use switch because cases are not fixed, there could be many number of counts. What other logic I can use to save time in a structure.

Comment: Use a container? e.g. `array`, `vector`, etc.

Comment: @Rotem when count is 1, I saved the time in array but when count is 2 it will overwrite the first time values. ? or may be I didn't get what you are trying to say.

Comment: Not if you use `count` as an index into the array, or instead just use `vector::push_back`.

Comment: @Rotem can you give an example

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use a container, such as a [`std::vector`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/vector/vector/) to store your time values.

```
std::vector<SYSTEMTIME> savedTimes;
```

---

```
SYSTEMTIME time;
if (input == high)
{
    //count++; //count is redundant now, you can later just check savedTimes.size()
    GetLocalTime(&time);
    savedTimes.push_back(time); //will add another value to the end of the vector.
}
```

---

do something with your stored times:

```
for (auto it = savedTimes.begin(); it != savedTimes.end(); ++it)
{
    SYSTEMTIME time = *it;
    //whatever...
}
```

or

```
for (int i = 0; i < savedTimes.size(); i++)
{
    SYSTEMTIME time = savedTimes[i];
    //whatever...
}
```

Comment: It is great. But how would I know which savedTime is for which count value. Further I also need to subtract time values and for that I will need to convert them to file time. Is it possible using vectors.?

Comment: @Andrew I added an example where you can also access the vector values by index, so you know which value is what index. Regarding subtraction and file times, that has nothing to do with the original question or vectors. I suggest you ask a new question that discusses this regardless of storing multiple values in a container.

Comment: I have tried it my self and added a solution. Please have a look at it.

Answer (score -1):

I have solved the problem by using array of structures.

```
struct foo 
 {
  WORD Year;
  WORD Month;
  WORD DayOfWeek;
  WORD Day;
  WORD Hour;
  WORD Minute;
  WORD Second;
  WORD Milliseconds;
};

struct foo Foo[20]
```

now whenever the input is high:

```
if(input==high)
{
 count++;
 GetLocalTime(&time);


//This will copy complete time in Foo[0]. 
//So next time input is high, time will get copied in Foo[1] and this will keep on going..
 memcpy(&Foo[count],&time,sizeof(Foo)); 

}
```

Now I want to know how to clear the structure `Foo`.?

Comment: Downvoting is ok but please try adding a comment so that I can understand what mistake I have done in my logic.